# Transaction for different databases

Tags: c#, asp.net, transactions, transactionscope

I use 2 different dlls to connect to 2 database in my project . each dll has it's own DAL layer .

now in a page I need to insert a set of related data into these 2 databases . I want to use transaction to make sure data are inserted correctly . but as I just have access to public methods of Insert() of each assembly , not the ADO.net codes . how can I handle this situation ? is there anything like this in c# ?

```
beginTransaction(){
  dll1.class.Insert(data);
  dll2.className.Insert(relatedData);
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the [`TransactionScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) class:

> Makes a code block transactional.

Example usage:

```
using (var tx = new TransactionScope())
{
  dll1.class.Insert(data);
  dll2.className.Insert(relatedData);

  tx.Complete(); // if not executed, transaction will rollback
}
```

As [@Anders Abel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/280222/anders-abel) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11712436/transaction-for-different-databases#comment15537024_11712449), the servers running the databases involved in the transaction will need the MSDTC service to be running and configured correctly on both the DB servers and the client machines. The [DTCPing](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2868) utility is very helpful in this regard.

As [Steve B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/588868/steve-b) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11712436/transaction-for-different-databases#comment15537067_11712449), there is an assumption here that all the databases and the associated drivers support distributed transaction enlistment. Check your documentation...

Comment: Please note that using `TransactionScope` to make a transaction span two databases will require the MSDTC service running on the DB servers, with correct network configuration (which can be tricky to get secure in a non domain environment).

Comment: @AndersAbel - True. This is where [DTCPing](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2868) is a godsend.

Comment: And it also suppose that the two DB drivers support the distributed transaction enlistment. What are the database your are working with?

Comment: I'm using sql server 2008 on a shared host ? are these enough for this scenario ?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 is fine for this. The shared hosting may very well be a problem - you need to discuss this with the hosting company (MSDTC is tricky at best and I don't know what most hosting companies do).